# Calculate longest path for undirected graph where vertices can be visited several times but edges ONLY ONCE

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, jgrapht

I have an undirected graph and want to calculate the longest possible path between two vertices, where every edge can be visited ONLY ONCE but every vertex can be visited several times.

All the longest path solutions I found with JTGraph always operate on the premise that every vertex is only visited once.

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution do not come to mind, but this can be done using `min-cost-max-flow` algorithm:

1. Build a flow network where edges have capacity of `1` and value of `-1`
2. Now running min cost max flow algorithm will find a flow of minimum cost from starting node to sink node - since our costs are negative this will find longest path that repeats vertices and uses edges only once